# Boot from grub2.cfg an other bootloader… in same disk

Tags: linux, grub2, mbr

In my USB multiboot i have installed grub2 and edit the first file grub.cfg... now, have created an second partition with an other iso(dd if=file.iso of=/dev/2)...The second iso then created the MBR in firsts sector of the second partition. Now, how i can do boot MBR of the second parition from FIRST(principal) file grub2.cfg?